# Restkit + MKStoreKit: duplicate symbol because of JSONKit

Tags: xcode4, restkit, duplicate-symbol, mkstorekit

I'm using MKStoreKit in my application. Now I'd like to add RestKit as well, but after adding RestKit, I get the following error message in XCode:

`Duplicate symbol _jk_collectionClassLoadTimeInitialization in [...]/libRestKitJSONParserJSONKit.a(JSONKit.o) and [...]/Objects-normal/armv7/JSONKit.o for architecture armv7`

Any ideas what I can do about it?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: If I remove the JSONKit from MKStoreKit, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: I had the same 'clash' when i tried to use facebook-sdk. I just removed the embedded JSONKit from the facebook framework (in your case from MKStoreKit)..The root cause is that you have the JSONKit twice in your project

Comment: but then, it says that it doesn't find `objectFromJSONData` - although this method is also in the remaining (RESTKit)-JSONKit.h/.m...

Comment: did you updated your target's Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries to link against RestKit's JSONKit?

Comment: yes: I link against 6 libraries from RestKit: libRestKitXMLParserLibxml, libRestKitCoreData, libRestKitJSONParserJSONKit, libRestKitNetwork, libRestKitObjectMapping, libRestKitSupport

Comment: What exactly does the error say? Is it compiler or linker?

Comment: okay, try removing just the JSONKit.m from MKStoreKit, leaving the header in place.

Comment: looks good! won't you write a "real" answer with that solution please? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That error is caused by a clash between JSONKit framework bundled with MKStoreKit and the fact that`RestKit brings in the JSONKit as well.

The simplest solution is to remove `JSONKit.m` file from your project (the one that came with MKStoreKit) and keep the `JSONKit.h` header. Be sure to link your project with the JSONKit that is provided with RestKit framework. This will allow your project to 'see' the JSONKit and the linker links it with the bundled library.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with Deezer and AdFonic static library. But both of libraries are closed source. In this case, the solution is then to remove symbols from library.

Nathan de Vries post a great tutorial here:

http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries/